# Spring probe center dimension

Tags: test, probe

Im looking at some spring probes, such as are used in test fixtures (NOT on multimeters or scopes).

All the catalogues (Ingun, Coda-Pin, etc) seem to organise by a dimension they call "centers" but never seem to show a matching dimension on diagrams... what is a "center" in this context?

Ta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's how close together you can crowd the pins in your test fixture. If your test pads are 2mm apart, you need probes that work at 2mm centres or smaller. The max diameter has to be somewhat smaller than this...

Comment: +1, I have seen at least one diagram showing the distance between pogos, marked as "Centers".

Answer (score 1):

Since IC's come in a variety of standard pitches (measured from pin to pin center), spring probes are designed to match the typical pitch of IC's used on the board.

Often they are defined as "grid" spacing which is same as pad "centers" or "pitch".

The diameter of the pins are just over 50% of the minimum grid space and are knurled or crimped to fit snug when the drill size is 0.01~0.03 mm over the plain shaft diameter.